Docker File Creating Artifact Instead of Docker Image on Azure
I am working on writing a workflow in GIT. I am using yaml file  and running the docker file. For some reason, on the Azure Container Registry, it is creating a Artifact instead of Docker Image. I tried changes context on the yaml file but it did not help. Does anyone know why its creating an artifact instead of a docker image. I am able to create the docker image locally.
Following is from yaml file:
- name: Build and Push Docker image

  uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
  with:
    context: .
    file: src/WebApi/Dockerfile
    push: true
    tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
    labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}
    build-args: |
        NODE_AUTH_TOKEN
        NODE_MAJOR_VERSION
    secret-files: |
        nugetconfig=../nuget.config
 env:
    NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
    NODE_MAJOR_VERSION: ${{ vars.NODE_VERSION }}

Thank you,
Kim
Expecting to have docker image on Azure Registry.

Dockerfile was build and pushed to ACR after I changed the tag name and updated your yml file like below:-
name: Build and Push Docker Image

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Set up Docker Buildx
      uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2

    - name: Login to Azure Container Registry
      uses: azure/docker-login@v1
      with:
        login-server: siliconacr9.azurecr.io
        username: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CR_USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CR_PASSWORD }}

    - name: Build and Push Docker image
      uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
      with:
        context: .
        file: Dockerfile
        push: true
        tags: siliconacr9.azurecr.io/app1:${{ github.sha }}
        labels: type=image

Make sure to have your AZURE_CR_PASSWORD and AZURE_CR_USERNAME added in the Github Action Repository Secret:-


Also make sure your Dockerfile path is correct:-
context: . 
file: src/WebApi/Dockerfile

Output:-


As an alternative you can use Docker build and push command in Docker login task only as given in this MS document. You can refer this document to build and push node app Dockerfile to ACR and ACI
 - name: 'Build and push image'
          uses: azure/docker-login@v1
          with:
            login-server: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_LOGIN_SERVER }}
            username: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CR_USERNAME }}
            password: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CR_PASSWORD }}
        - run: |
            docker build . -t ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_LOGIN_SERVER }}/sampleapp:${{ github.sha }}
            docker push ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_LOGIN_SERVER }}/sampleapp:${{ github.sha }}

